# Why is Dagger2 asking me to provide something that the component is not supposed to provide?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm playing around trying to learn Dagger2. Just when I thought I was getting it, I seem to have gotten stuck. My application has two components, ApplicationComponent (singleton) and StripeComponent (1:1 activity) , which inherit an empty interface for the sake of readability.

Then it has two modules, ApplicationModule and StripeModule.

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AbstractComponent ...

@PerActivity @Component(modules = { StripeModule.class }) public interface StripeComponent
extends AbstractComponent ...

@Module public class ApplicationModule
@Module public class StripeModule
```

One of the objects ApplicationModule provides is a Navigator, and I'm fairly sure than the way it does it is fairly correct:

```
@Provides @Singleton Navigator provideNavigator() {
  return new Navigator();
}
```

This is a very simple class with pretty much nothing in it yet:

```
@Singleton public class Navigator
```

Then when I generate the code, an extra provision factory is generated from StripeModule - StripeModule_ProvideNavigatorFactory. And then the compiler whines that I'm not providing it - which is true, and intentional. It should be provided by the application component only. The question is, why is this factory being generated then? Why doesn't Dagger2  understand that StripeModule is not supposed to provide a navigator?

Comment: Are you trying to inherit `Navigator` from the `@Singleton` scope component into your `@PerActivity` scope? If you are injecting your `StripeActivity` in such a way that `@Inject Navigator navigator;` through your `StripeComponent` then you'll need to provide the navigator. Which is why I am asking if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, just please include the code for `StripeModule`, `ApplicationModule`, and the class that you are trying to inject with one of these components (especially if it contains `@Inject Navigator navigator;`)

Comment: Ah well, I just wrote an answer based on what I think you want, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a `StripeActivity` class that uses `StripeComponent` to inject itself, then you might end up with a scenario like this one

```
public class StripeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        CustomApplication application = (CustomApplication)getApplicationContext();
        StripeComponent stripeComponent = createComponent(application);
        stripeComponent.inject(this);
    }

    protected StripeComponent createComponent(CustomApplication application) {
        return DaggerStripeComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(application.getApplicationComponent())
                .build();
    }
}

public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationComponent = createApplicationComponent();
    }

    protected ApplicationComponent createApplicationComponent() {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.create();
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return applicationComponent;
    }
}

@Component(modules={ApplicationModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Navigator navigator();
}

@Component(dependencies={ApplicationComponent.class}, modules={StripeModule.class})
@PerActivity
public interface StripeComponent extends ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(StripeActivity stripeActivity);
}

@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Navigator navigator() {
        return new Navigator();
    }
}

@Module
public class StripeModule {
    //@Provides
    //@PerActivity
    //...
}

@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity {
}
```

EDIT: For base class injection, you need to inject both the superclass and the subclass manually, and you need to specify both the superclass and the subclass in your component. In this case, it would work like this.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        CustomApplication application = (CustomApplication)getApplicationContext();
        ApplicationComponent component = createComponentAndInjectSelf(application);
        component.inject(this);
    }

    protected abstract ApplicationComponent createComponentAndInjectSelf(CustomApplication application);
}

public class StripeActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public StripeComponent createComponentAndInjectSelf(CustomApplication application) {
        StripeComponent stripeComponent = DaggerStripeComponent.builder()
            .applicationComponent(application.getApplicationComponent())
            .build();
        stripeComponent.inject(this);
        return stripeComponent;
    }
}

@Component(modules={ApplicationModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Navigator navigator();

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);
}

@Component(dependencies={ApplicationComponent.class}, modules={StripeModule.class})
@PerActivity
public interface StripeComponent extends ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(StripeActivity stripeActivity);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was answering your comment but I had to leave. You were totally right on your first comment: StripeActivity inherits an abstract activity that I use for the global dependencies, those provided by the ApplicationModule. However, it doesn't feel like the right thing to do to provide the navigator from both modules, mostly because it will end up in a lot of duplicated code, as the navigator is not the only dependency provided by ApplicationComponent. I'm guessing this code you posted is the proper way to avoid these duplications, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Base class injection is tricky because you have to call inject both in the superclass and in the subclass, and you need to specify both the superclass and the subclass in your component, I'll add that in an edit.

Comment: Alright, verified it now, thanks a lot and sorry that I didn't have time before.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the exact error, or the code that actually depends on the `Navigator`.

But I'll assume the class that depends on `Navigator` is provided from within `StripeModule` or another module installed into `StripeComponent`.

`StripeComponent` and `ApplicationComponent` have to be related in some way in order for bindings in `StripeComponent` to use bindings provided by `ApplicationComponent`.

You can relate them either using [component dependencies](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies) or [subcomponents](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#subcomponents).

If you use subcomponents, you'd make `StripeComponent` a subcomponent of `ApplicationComponent`, which would mean that it can use any of the bindings in modules installed in `ApplicationComponent`, including the one for `Navigator`.

If you want to use component dependencies, you'd make `StripeComponent` depend on `ApplicationComponent`, and you'd add a method `Navigator navigator()` to `ApplicationComponent`. Bindings in `StripeComponent` can depend on any type returned by a method on a component it depends on.